# TensorFlow CNN with 3D input is too slow to train

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

## Problem

I am building a TensorFlow CNN in Python 2.7 to classify 40x40x40 3D images into one of the two categories. The training data is stored in a HDF5 file as a (5000,40,40,40,1) array (5000 training images, 1 color channel). However, when I am training the network, each iteration of a batch of 32 images takes about a minute to complete. Through Activity Monitor I see that there are about 6GB data written to the disk in each iteration. The HDF5 itself is only about 500MB. What is happening?

This is the code I used to load data:

```
f = h5py.File(file_name, 'r')
images = f.get('key_name')
images = np.array(images)
images = images.astype(np.float32)
images = np.multiply(images, 1.0 / 100.0)
```

I also tried to directly use a HDF5 object for each iteration, instead of loading all the data into memory at once. But the problem remains:

```
f = h5py.File(file_name, 'r')
images = np.array(f.get('key_name')[:batch_size])
```

## CNN Structure

The CNN I built has two 3D convolution layer, one flatten layer, one fully connected layer and one output layer. Here is the complete code for the structure:

```
num_channels = 1 
filter_size_conv1 = 5
filter_size_conv2 = 5 
num_filters_conv1 = 32
num_filters_conv2 = 64
fc_layer_size = 64 

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, img_size, img_size, img_size, num_channels], name='x')
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], name='y_true')
y_true_cls = tf.argmax(y_true, dimension=1)

def create_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))

def create_biases(size):
    return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05,shape=[size]))

def create_convolutional_layer(input,
               num_input_channels, 
               conv_filter_size,        
               num_filters):     
    weights = create_weights(shape=[
        conv_filter_size, conv_filter_size, conv_filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters])
    biases = create_biases(num_filters)
    layer = tf.nn.conv3d(input=input,
                     filter=weights,
                     strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                     padding='SAME')
    layer += biases
    layer = tf.nn.max_pool3d(input=layer,
                            ksize=[1, 4, 4, 4, 1],
                            strides=[1, 4, 4, 4, 1],
                            padding='SAME')
    layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
    return layer

def create_flatten_layer(layer):
    layer_shape = layer.get_shape()
    num_features = layer_shape[1:5].num_elements()  
    layer = tf.reshape(layer, [-1, num_features])
    return layer

def create_fc_layer(input,          
             num_inputs,    
             num_outputs,
             use_relu=True):    
    weights = create_weights(shape=[num_inputs, num_outputs])
    biases = create_biases(num_outputs) 
    layer = tf.matmul(input, weights) + biases
    if use_relu:
        layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
    return layer


layer_conv1 = create_convolutional_layer(input=x,
               num_input_channels=num_channels,
               conv_filter_size=filter_size_conv1,
               num_filters=num_filters_conv1)

layer_conv2 = create_convolutional_layer(input=layer_conv1,
               num_input_channels=num_filters_conv1,
               conv_filter_size=filter_size_conv2,
               num_filters=num_filters_conv2)

layer_flat = create_flatten_layer(layer_conv2)

layer_fc1 = create_fc_layer(input=layer_flat,
                     num_inputs=layer_flat.get_shape()[1:5].num_elements(),
                     num_outputs=fc_layer_size,
                     use_relu=True)

layer_fc2 = create_fc_layer(input=layer_fc1,
                     num_inputs=fc_layer_size,
                     num_outputs=num_classes,
                     use_relu=False)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the same problem here. I'm using conv3d and it takes like forever to finish. Probably related to the optimization of conv3d

Comment: Do you find a way to get around this? Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that it has to do with memory space and whether you have a GPU. When I ran it with a GPU and huge memory, it finished really fast